# Create a mesh- No watertight

Tags: meshlab

I have a point cloud that I would like to turn into a triangulated mesh. I am not interested in a watertight model, I just want to create the triangles between the points. Which of the options in Meshlab would be the most appropriate to do that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try any of the following filters under `Filters -> Remeshing, Simplification, and Reconstruction`

- Delaunay Triangulation
- Marching Cubes (APSS)
- Marching Cubes (RIMLS)
- Surface Reconstruction: Ball Pivoting
- Surface Reconstruction: VCG
- Screened Poisson Surface Reconstruction

All of these have different parameters, except for the first one, which is probably what you want.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your suggestions, really appreciated. I will try with those.